# Error when testing fetch in vanilla JavaScript with jest-fetch-mock

Tags: javascript, api, jestjs, jest-fetch-mock

I'm trying to test a fetch from a class. I need to create a class instance to access the fetch method.
If I eliminate the class and return directly, the method works.

I tried to do the test this way, but it returns undefined. Any solution?

Thank you very much

```
//api.test.js
//import the class Request and module jest-fetch-mock
import Request from './index'
global.fetch = require('jest-fetch-mock')

describe('testing api', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    fetch.resetMocks()
  })

  it('calls api and returns data to me', async () => {
    const request = new Request('http://localhost:3000/api.json')
    fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify({data: '12345'}))

    // assert on the response
    const res = request.getSections()
    expect(res.data).toEqual('12345')


    // assert on the times called and arguments given to fetch
    expect(fetch.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1)
    expect(fetch.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual('http://localhost:3000/api.json')
  })
})

//api.js
/**
* Request Component
* @class Request
*/
class Request {
/**
* Creates an instance of Request
*
* @param {String}  url - The url of the API
* @throws {Error} - Incorrect type
* @memberof Request
*/
  constructor(url) {
     if (typeof url !== 'string') throw TypeError(`${url} is not a string`)
     this.url = url
  }

  /**
  * Handler get sections from api
  * @memberof Request
  */
  getSections() {
     return fetch(this.url)// eslint-disable-line
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then(result => result.sections)
       .catch(err => console.error(err)) // eslint-disable-line
  }
}

export default Request
```

I received:

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected)

Expected value to equal:
  "12345"
Received:
  undefined

Difference:

  Comparing two different types of values. Expected string but received undefined.

  14 |     // assert on the response
  15 |     const res = request.getSections()
> 16 |     expect(res.data).toEqual('12345')
     |                      ^
  17 |
  18 |
  19 |     // assert on the times called and arguments given to fetch
```

Res is undefined too. I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 2):

I see two problems that you can fix to get things working.

The first is that because `getSections` is an asynchronous function (it returns a promise), you need to call it asynchronously from your test.  Your test method is already marked as `async`, so all you need to do is add the `await` keyword before the call.

```
const res = await request.getSections()
```

Secondly, your `Request` code is expecting a server response that includes a `sections` property, which your mock does not have.  Try changing your mock to include a `sections` property, such as:

```
fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify({ sections: { data: "12345" }}));
```

If you make these two changes, your test should pass.